# Import MySQLdb not working in python

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, mysql-python

I have executed the following command to install mysqldb :

```
apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

it returned :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-mysqldb is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 381 not upgraded.
```

But when i try to run a file with code :

```
import MySqldb;
```

through

```
python index.py
```

it returns :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "index.py", line 1, in <module>
import MySqldb;
ImportError: No module named MySqldb
```

Please help..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is called `MySQLdb` - watch the case:

```
import MySQLdb
```

Demo:

```
>>> import MySqldb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySqldb
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> MySQLdb.__version__
'1.2.5'
```